# How to find the asymptotes of the graph $y=\frac{x^2-5x-4}{x^2-5x+4}$?

Tags: functions

I just came across this question asking me to find the asymptotes of

$$y=\frac{x^2-5x-4}{x^2-5x+4}$$

I typed this into my graphics calculator but I've never seen this type of graph before so this is something new. Currently studying functions.

Would someone be able to explain to me thoroughly how to solve this problem and how to go about this type of questions in general?

Thank you!

Comment: There are two things to look at : what does happen when $x$ tends to a root of the denominator and when $x\to\pm \infty$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh I see. So x cannot be 1 or 5 in this case as for when x tends to a root of the denominator. Would you be able to explain what happens when x tends towards infinity, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y=\frac{x^2-5x-4}{x^2-5x+4}$$

Rewriting:
$$y=\frac{x^2-5x+4-8}{x^2-5x+4}$$

$$y=1-\frac8{x^2-5x+4}$$

So if you take the limit as x approaches infinity:

$$lim_{x\to\infty}(1- \frac8{x^2-5x+4})=1$$

So the curve will be pretty close to $y=1$ as x gets larger, so it is the horizontal asymptote

Then we need to see if the denominator of the fraction can get arbitrarily small, that is, if the denominator could be equal to 0.

Turns out; $$x^2-5x+4=(x-4)(x-1)$$

So when x approaches those $4$ or $1$, the value of y will tend to infinity. So $x=4$ and $x=1$ are the vertical asymptote

Comment: Note that in general, you should check that solutions to the denominator are not _also_ solutions to the numerator (they are not in this case). Because if they _are_, then you may not actually have a vertical asymptote.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) &=\frac{x^2-5x-4}{x^2-5x+4}\\
&= \frac{x^2-5x+4 - 8}{x^2-5x+4}=1-\frac{8}{x^2-5x+4}\\
&=1-\frac{8}{(x-1)(x-4)}\\
&=1+\frac{8}{3} \left( \frac{1}{x-1} -\frac{1}{x-4} \right)
\end{aligned}$$